# EJB specifications and Java versions - backwards compatibility

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, ejb, ejb-2.x

This is my understanding of relationship between the EJB spec and Java versions

- EJB 2.0 was part of J2EE 1.3 platform, which was on top J2SE 1.3
  or JDK 1.3.x
- EJB 2.1 was part of J2EE 1.4 platform, which was on top of J2SE 1.4 or JDK 1.4.x

*The EJB 2.1 specification requires backward compatibility for EJB 2.0, so containers supporting EJB 2.1 and running in JDK 1.4.x will be able to run EJB 2.0 beans as well.*

- EJB 3.0 is part of Java EE 5 platform, which required Java SE 5 (JDK 5) for annotations etc

*The EJB 3 spec requires backward compatibility for earlier version of the specifications.*

**My question is this. If I upgrade the java code for the implementation of the EJB 2.0 beans to compile against a later version of Java (say Java 5), can I still keep the same version of the EJB spec or do I need to migrate this as well.**

Comment: Voted up since it helped me created http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921562/how-backwards-compatible-are-ejb-containers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't even have to "upgrade" the Java code, since I think older code can only be incompatible at source level due to identifiers that collide with newly introduced keywords, but that's not a problem at the bytecode level.

So your old Java 1.3/EJB 2.0 EARs should still run unchanged on a Java 5/EJB 3 appserver, and you could even do bugfixes in code and compile it with `-target 1.3` on a modern JDK without having to fix the colliding identifiers (of course you then also cannot use the new source-level features).

Comment: Thanks, does this mean I could keep using the EJB 2.0 version of the EJB spec and at the same time take advantage of some of the features of Java 5 within implementation of my beans?

Comment: @AJM: Yes, though that of course requires you to update your source completely to Java 5 (which isn't too bad, just rename identifiers that collide with new keywords).

Answer (score 3):

This [table](http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/java/versions/ejb.html) shows several incompatibilities at the source (build-time) level between ejb 2.0, 2.1 and 3.0 versions, although binary (run-time) compatibility is supported for all releases, i.e. you can run your code on the new ejb versions without the need to recompile.

[image]