# How backwards compatible are EJB containers?

Tags: jboss, ejb, backwards-compatibility, specifications

I have inherited an application that is running on JBoss 2.4.3 (which I believe is EJB spec 2.0 compatible), and I'm running into quite a few issues (like being able to use *modern* log4j "Logger" apis [JBoss 2.4 specific issues pushing me to upgrade]).

I understand that I should be able to use a EJB 2.1 container (Jboss 4) without issue, but should I expect to be able to go further?

What are the backwards compatibility requirements for EJB?

Are they meant to be backwards compatible through major versions?

Do application vendors make them fully backwards compatible?

What modifications are necessary to make an older application conform? (small or large? application configuration or re-compilation? etc)

Comment: I don't get any exceptions, because I have decided to ask for knowledge rather than run the gauntlet of trying out 4 versions of jboss and spending 3 days "playing". (I'm in this for the quick win ... ... I think that's an oxymoron for EJB, but I'd like to try).

Comment: I guess the fact that you asked what exceptions I get indicates that later versions are not drop-in compatible :)

Answer (score 1):

log4j and EJB 2.0 are not related. If you have problems with log4j, then most likely it is a class path issue and not EJB 2.0 compatbility issue. Probably your old application assumes that log4j is somewhere on system class path.

Comment: The issue is that jboss 2.4 uses log4j 1.1, and extends CategoryFactory which is not in 1.2 (and so eliminating it from the classpath is not an option). It spews out masses of info level messages that cannot be turned off in the manner I am familiar with (or any way at all really).

Comment: Well, that's rather JBoss and log4j issue, then an EJB specification issue. If your are app is specifically designed to use features of JBoss 2.4, then of course it may not be compatibale with later versions of JBoss and other containers. But if the app uses purely EJB specification it should be comptabile.

Answer (score 1):

http://what-when-how.com/enterprise-javabeans-3/backward-compatibility-and-interoperability-with-ejb-2/ states that

> The EJB 3 specification requires that all complying containers support EJB 2

Which is a good sign. It goes on further to talk about mixing EJB 2 and 3 functionality. So there may be some exceptions, but it really shouldn't be any where near impossible.

Reality may be different; I'll update if I find problems with my jboss upgrade.

Comment: ...support EJB 2.x programming model, *as specified in the EJB 3 specification*.  Each new specification clarifies ambiguities that can introduce subtle incompatibilities.

Answer (score 1):

See [this compatibility report](http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/java/versions/ejb.html) for the EJB library:

[image]