# Can we use EJB(3.0) in JDK 1.4

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

As of now we are using EJB 3.0 in JDK 1.6 Environment. Due to some restriction we are forced to use JDK1.4 instead of JDK1.6.

**Now my question is will Ejb's(3.0) work on jdk1.4 environment.I want to use Remote EJB's**.

Please let me the props and cons of using this environment so that i could proceed further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: No

EJB 3.0 is an extension of EJB 2.0 (well sort off) so please check what features of EJB you are using.

Get the updated version of Java 1.4.

From: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25221_04/web.1013/b14432/intro.htm#i1049638
""
Support for New J2EE 1.4 Application Management and Deployment Specifications

OC4J supports the following specifications defining new standards for deploying and managing applications in a J2EE environment.

```
The Java Management Extensions (JMX) 1.2 specification, which allows standard interfaces to be created for managing resources, such as services and applications, in a J2EE environment. The OC4J implementation of JMX provides a JMX client that can be used to completely manage an OC4J server and applications running within it.

The J2EE Management Specification (JSR-77), a specification that allows standard components to be created for managing applications in a J2EE environment.

The J2EE Application Deployment API (JSR-88), which defines a standard API for configuring and deploying J2EE applications and modules into a J2EE-compatible environment. The OC4J implementation includes the ability to create and/or edit a deployment plan containing the OC4J-specific configuration data needed to deploy a component into OC4J.
```

Support for Enterprise JavaBeans 3.0

OC4J provides support for Enterprise JavaBeans 3.0, including the new program annotation functionality, as defined in the Early Draft Review specification. The specification is available at the following link:

http://java.sun.com/products/ejb/

Note that OC4J must use JDK 5.0 to enable EJB 3.0 support.
""

Comment: Hi,I am using Remote Beans (session beans) using JNDI search. Is there any way how we can handle this in jdk1.4.

Comment: Have you tried running your webapp / ear with java 1.4? Is so, what containers did you use? Please provide us with your research updates.

Answer (score 1):

Quote to [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31017_01/web.1013/b28221/undejsup001.htm) doc:

> What JDK is Required?
>
> By default, if you are using EJB 3.0, then you must use **JDK 1.5**. By
>   default, OC4J does not support the use of EJB 3.0 and JDK 1.4.

EDIT:

StackOverflow thread : [EJB specifications and Java versions - backwards compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297356/ejb-specifications-and-java-versions-backwards-compatibility)

Comment: I wonder what they mean by "by default" (they even say it twice).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what container are you running your EJB3 in.
So, I don't know about OC4J but you can run into trouble running your application server on 1.4 even before you're going to work with EJB3 :) So, in short don't do this.